# How to add a like and unlike system for a social media application using firebase and nextjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, tailwind-css

I have created this much but it is kind of static because of the index of **1**.

```
const htmlJSX = (
        <div className='text-gray-100'>
            <Navbar title={currentData.title} />
            <div className='w-10/12 p-3 dark-glassmorph mx-auto my-10 md:flex md:gap-10' >
                <div>
                    <img src={currentData.image} className="rounded-md" />
                    <h1 className='text-gray-300 mt-3'><button onClick={() => {
                        if(currentData.likedBy[1].name === email){
 

                       setLiked(false)
                        updateDoc(doc(db, 'posts', currentData.id), {
                            likes: Number(currentData.likes-1),
                            likedBy: arrayRemove({name: localStorage.getItem("email")})
                        })
                        refreshag()
                    }
                    else {
                        setLiked(true)
                        updateDoc(doc(db, 'posts', currentData.id), {
                            likes: Number(currentData.likes+1),
                            likedBy: arrayUnion({name: localStorage.getItem("email")})
                        })
                        refreshag()
                    }
                }} className=''>{liked ? (<span className='text-red-600'><AiFillHeart size={30} /></span>) : (<AiOutlineHeart size={30} />)}</button><span className='absolute mt-1 ml-2'>{currentData.likes} Likes</span></h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src={currentData.image} />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

I expected it to check each and every array to find if the mail is there or not

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to test if a specific element is in the array using a predicate:

```js
if (currentData.likedBy.find(a => a.name === email)) {

// You can also use object destructuring:
if (currentData.likedBy.find(({ name }) => name === email)) {
```

Comment: Thanks! it works, but can you also please tell me how to use this code in the useEffect function so that it gets this data when we refresh this page, because this code is not working in useEffect

Comment: @SpywarePerseus What have you tried so far? Maybe post another question with that

Comment: I got help from another stackoverflow questions and now it works! Thanks a lot though! You helped me a lot!